# Git color.ui not working with git 2.0 on os x 10.9

Tags: git, terminal, osx-mavericks

Hey I have tried everything to enable colors in git, also [this](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-colours-in-git). In windows there was no problems but on my new mac I can't make it work.

I have installed git 2.0 via Homebrew

Normally this is all what it takes: git config --global color.ui true

Comment: after adding that config to .gitconfig file did you do `$ source ~/.gitconfig` ?

Comment: No what is the command doing? can you please explain it

Comment: Is your terminal declared as `xterm-color`? (as in http://superuser.com/a/234928/141)

Comment: Has just tried all the color settings

Comment: I don't know if it's because i booted my mac or something else, but its working now, so this case is closed.

Comment: `$ source ~/.gitconfig` will load your new settings that you put in `.gitconfig`